# hadoop namenode,datanode,secondarynamenode are not starting up

Tags: hadoop

I just downloaded hadoop-0.20 tar and extracted. And i set JAVA_HOME and HADOOP_HOME. I modified core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml and mapred-site.xml.

I started services.

```
  jps


 jps
 JobTracker
 TaskTracker
```

I check the logs. It says

```
 2015-02-11 18:07:52,278 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG:

 /************************************************************
 STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
 STARTUP_MSG:   host = scspn0022420004.lab.eng.btc.netapp.in/10.72.40.68
 STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
 STARTUP_MSG:   version = 0.20.0
 STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/core/branches/branch-0.20 -r 763504; compiled by 'ndaley' on Thu Apr  9 05:18:40 UTC 2009
 ************************************************************/
  2015-02-11 18:07:52,341 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:134)
    at   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(NameNode.java:156)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(NameNode.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:279)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:955)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:964)

    2015-02-11 18:07:52,346 INFO   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
   /************************************************************
   SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at   scspn0022420004.lab.eng.btc.netapp.in/10.72.40.68
   ************************************************************/
```

What i am mistaking?

My Conf files as follows:

core-site

```
 <configuration>
  <property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
  </property>
 </configuration>
```

hdfs-site

```
 <configuration>
  <property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
 </property>
 <!-- Immediately exit safemode as soon as one DataNode checks in.
   On a multi-node cluster, these configurations must be removed.  -->
 <property>
   <name>dfs.safemode.extension</name>
   <value>0</value>
  </property>
  <property>
   <name>dfs.safemode.min.datanodes</name>
   <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
   <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
   <value>/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/${user.name}</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:///var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/${user.name}/dfs/name</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir</name>
    <value>file:///var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/${user.name}/dfs/namesecondary</value>
   </property>
   <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:///var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/${user.name}/dfs/data</value>
   </property>

  </configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
  <configuration>
   <property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>localhost:8021</value>
   </property>
  </configuration>
```

Any idea?

This is what i see in the console while starting `start-dfs.sh`

```
 localhost: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /root/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.0/bin/../logs/hadoop-root-secondarynamenode- hostname.out
 localhost: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 localhost:      at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:134)
 localhost:      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(NameNode.java:156)
 localhost:      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(NameNode.java:160)
 localhost:      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.initialize(SecondaryNameNode.java:131)
 localhost:      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.<init>   (SecondaryNameNode.java:115)
 localhost:      at   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.main(SecondaryNameNode.java:469)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [hadoop NullPointerException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490805/hadoop-nullpointerexception)

Comment: I am trying to setup single node . Not multinode and i don't see any error with master tagged as mentioned in that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you didn't set up your hadoop cluster correctly please follow these steps :

Step1: begin with setting up `.bashrc`:

```
vi $HOME/.bashrc
```

put the following lines at the end of the file: (change the hadoop home as yours)

```
# Set Hadoop-related environment variables
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop

# Set JAVA_HOME (we will also configure JAVA_HOME directly for Hadoop later on)
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun

# Some convenient aliases and functions for running Hadoop-related commands
unalias fs &> /dev/null
alias fs="hadoop fs"
unalias hls &> /dev/null
alias hls="fs -ls"

# If you have LZO compression enabled in your Hadoop cluster and
# compress job outputs with LZOP (not covered in this tutorial):
# Conveniently inspect an LZOP compressed file from the command
# line; run via:
#
# $ lzohead /hdfs/path/to/lzop/compressed/file.lzo
#
# Requires installed 'lzop' command.
#
lzohead () {
    hadoop fs -cat $1 | lzop -dc | head -1000 | less
}

# Add Hadoop bin/ directory to PATH
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

step 2 : edit `hadoop-env.sh` as following:

```
# The java implementation to use.  Required.
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
```

step 3 : Now  create a directory and set the required ownerships and permissions

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /app/hadoop/tmp
$ sudo chown hduser:hadoop /app/hadoop/tmp
# ...and if you want to tighten up security, chmod from 755 to 750...
$ sudo chmod 750 /app/hadoop/tmp
```

step 4 : edit `core-site.xml`

```
<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
</property>
```

step 5 : edit `mapred-site.xml`

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>localhost:54311</value>
</property>
```

step 6 : edit `hdfs-site.xml`

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
</property>
```

finally format your hdfs (You need to do this the first time you set up a Hadoop cluster)

```
 $ /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

hope this will help you

Comment: let me try this and i 'll let you know. Thanks for your steps

Comment: you're welcome (don't forget to change your JAVA_HOME and HADOOP_HOME as yours )

Comment: Chnages I made: 1) Modified bashrc. But i updated java and hadoop home in my path. Whats makes difference. 2) As Alfonso and you said, i modified core-site.xml. i) fs.default.name ii) created a directory. Thanks Sis :)

Comment: @ALL, Please follow these instructions to install hadoop. It works well.

Comment: And Do i need to create hduser. If so, please add those steps too. It 'll be useful for others

Comment: While that’s not required it is recommended because it helps to separate the Hadoop installation from other software applications and user accounts running on the same machine

Answer (score 1):

I don't use 0.20.0 version, but are you sure the key in core-site.xml is `fs.defaultFS`?
In [core-default.xml](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/tags/release-0.20.0/src/core/core-default.xml) seems to be named `fs.default.name`.

Comment: Thanks Alfonso. I changed this also. But i din't check what's the cause.